# Drupal Theming 'Add Content' Page

Tags: theming, users

Is there any module that can help me theming the "add content" page?

I'm also looking for a way to allow the use of the "add content" menu only to the users who paid.

When I talk about "add content" page, I'm actually talking about the template used when creating for example a new article page.

I don't want to give access to other users to the following fields, and basically change the whole look of that page.

- Menu settings
- Revision information
- URL path settings
- Comment settings
- Authoring information
- Publishing options

Comment: What do you mean by theme the "create content" ? The admin page ?

Comment: i mean i want to allow people to add content on my webpage in form of adds, but add content page is kinda complicate for a user to add it's own information on my ads page, hope this helps

Comment: Which version of Drupal you are using ?

Comment: i'm using drupal 7.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found and article explaining how to theme the node form here (http://batayneh.me/post/theming-node-forms-drupal-7). To solve the other part of your question - Only people who pay can use the "create content" you can create a new role and specify that only users with the new role can create content.

Comment: I'm pretty new to creating modules, i was looking for some already made, that guide would be useful for someone with more experience

Comment: link is down please re-check